How to avoid "trace buffers dropped" in TensorBoard trace analysis?
I'm profiling JAX code on TPU using jax.profiler.start_trace. I tried to reduce as much as possible the duration of the trace (running on a single v5e Chip, ...) but I still have more than 3/4 of the trace which is partially hidden by "trace buffers dropped", because of the 2GB protobuf file size limit. But the trace file is actually around 250 or 600MB, so there is a margin. I need to capture ~300s
How to avoid that? Increasing the protobuf file size, ...
I tried using jax.profiler.start_server , but nothing is collected... It seems to be adapted to shorter trace period.


How are you viewing the trace? IE : perfetto or tensorboard trace viewer?
Which file are you measuring? xplane.pb? or the trace.json?
How many seconds of trace are they successfully able to capture?



Tensorboard, exemple: jax.profiler.start_trace("/tmp/tensorboard") and then tensorboard --logdir /tmp/tensorboard.
I let Tensorboard choose, probably the xplane.pb?
On the CPU / Python part, I have the full trace. but on the TPU part, it traced <7s, and then all the remaining TPU is "trace buffers dropped".


Would it be possible to for you to share steps we can follow to reproduce this issue?

Sure, let's connect in 1-1

jax.profiler.start_server doesn't take a trace by itself. It allows you to use the Tensorboard UI for starting a trace (https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/profiling.html#manual-capture-via-tensorboard). This could be a good way to control how many seconds you're capturing.
That's odd that your trace is < 1GB, yet it says you're hitting the 2GB limit. I can't comment to ask questions that would help debug, so I suggest filing an issue at https://github.com/jax-ml/jax/issues and we can help you more there.
As a workaround, I suggest capturing many smaller traces instead of one large 300s trace.

As mentioned, I used jax.profiler.start_trace , I just tried jax.profiler.start_server as an unsuccessful workaround. Then I use Tensorboard to visualize the trace dumped.
